# Around 5-10% executors are LOST in my mesos framework

Tags: distributed-computing, mesos, mesosphere

I have a 200 node mesos cluster that can run around 2700 executors concurrently. Around 5-10% of my executors are LOST at the very beginning. They go only until extracting the executor tar file.

```
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR I0617 21:35:09.947180 45885 fetcher.cpp:76] Fetching URI 'http://download_url/remote_executor.tgz' I0617 21:35:09.947273 45885 fetcher.cpp:126] Downloading 'http://download_url/remote_executor.tgz' to '/mesos_dir/remote_executor.tgz' I0617 21:35:57.551722 45885 fetcher.cpp:64] Extracted resource '/mesos_dir/remote_executor.tgz' into '/extracting_mesos_dir/'
```

Please let me know if someone else is facing this issue.

I am using python to implement both the scheduler and executor. The executor code is a python file that extends base class 'Executor'. I have implemented the launchTasks method of Executor class that simply does what the executor is supposed to do.

The executor info is:

```
    executor = mesos_pb2.ExecutorInfo()
    executor.executor_id.value = "executor-%s" % (str(task_id),)
    executor.command.value = 'python -m myexecutor'

    # where to download executor from
    tar_uri = '%s/remote_executor.tgz' % (
        self.conf.remote_executor_cache_url)
    executor.command.uris.add().value = tar_uri
    executor.name = 'some_executor_name'
    executor.source = "executor_test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details about what your Executor is supposed to do  (at best ExecutorInfo Definition and the Executor itself)? What is the Command you use to start the executor (CommandInfo)?

For example definition of an executor have a look at [Rendler](https://github.com/mesosphere/RENDLER).
It includes a [sample executor](https://github.com/mesosphere/RENDLER/blob/master/cpp/crawl_executor.cpp) and the [ExecutorInfo definition](https://github.com/mesosphere/RENDLER/blob/master/cpp/rendler.cpp#L313).
Rendler are also includes samples in Java, GO, Python, Scala, and Haskell.

Comment: I've noticed that almost all LOST bundles are caused when executor tar file takes 40+ secs to download. Is there are timeout before which the executor has to register with mesos after downloading the tar file and extracting it?